# QTableWidget with automatic restore of old cell value

Tags: qt

I'm just getting started with QT, so please exercise a little patience...
I've an editable QTableWidget (actually a subclassing), and need to implement the following behavior. 
When the user types a non acceptable value I would like:
1) to restore the original value;
2) to keep the focus in the cell and set it in edit mode.

I'm currently using the itemChanged SIGNAL, and a subclassing of QTableWidgetItem.
Which one is the best way to get what I need?
Any tip, suggestion or reference is really welcome.

If you think it as useful I can post some code.

Ciao
Alf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a validator with QTableWidgetItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309715/how-to-use-a-validator-with-qtablewidgetitem)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently using the itemChanged SIGNAL...

You should subclass `QStyledItemDelegate`

```
class CustomTableDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        CustomTableDelegate (QObject * parent = 0);
        QWidget * createEditor (QWidget *, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &) const;
        bool editorEvent (QEvent *, QAbstractItemModel *, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &);
        void setEditorData (QWidget *, const QModelIndex &) const;
        void setModelData  (QWidget *, QAbstractItemModel *, const QModelIndex &) const;
};
```

And implement validation inside `setModelData`.

To use custom delegate you need set it for your `QTableWidget`:

```
table->setItemDelegate (new CustomTableDelegate () );
```

Comment: Can I do that with a single column using setItemDelegateForColumn?

Comment: No, you can’t. To check value for specific column you should check column number inside `setModelData` something like: `switch (index.column () ) {\\do stuff...}`.

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Thanks & Ciao